# How to get all XML nodes with tag name ending with a particular string

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a very trivial issue.
Let's assume that I have two "families" of xml documents: "requests" and "responses".

A document belonging to "requests" has at least one tag name that ends with "Request", like this one:

```
<MyMessage>
    <doSomethingRequest>
         ...
    </doSomethingRequest>
    ...
</MyMessage>
```

obviously a message belonging to "responses" would be

```
<MyMessage>
    <doSomethingResponse>
         ...
    </doSomethingResponse>
    ...
</MyMessage>
```

Now the question is very easy. How can I understand in an efficient way if a message belongs to one of the two families?

I've tried something like:

```
public static String getMessageFamily(Document xml){
    if(xml.getElementsByTagName("*Request").getLength() != 0){
        return "I'm a Request!";
    } else if(xml.getElementsByTagName("*Response").getLength() != 0){
        return "I'm a Response!";
    } else {
        return "don't know who I am";
    }
}
```

but apparently this does not work (actually I was pretty sure that this was not working since wildcards in `org.w3c.dom.Document` are allowed only standalone to match all tags).

Any Idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, the question is trivial, and so is the answer: use XPath, with function ends-with.

```
public static String getMessageType(Document xml) {
    try {
        xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();


        XPathExpression searchRequest = xpath.compile("//*[ends-with(name(),'Request')]");
        XPathExpression searchResponse = xpath.compile("//*[ends-with(name(),'Response')]");
        NodeList requestResult = (NodeList) searchRequest.evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList responseResult = (NodeList) searchResponse.evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        if(requestResult.getLength() != 0) return "REQ";
        if(responseResult.getLength() != 0) return "RESP";
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (XPathFactoryConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```